# Is denying Christ under the threat of death not a mortal sin?

Tags: catholicism, repentance, martyrdom, mortal-sin

I heard that if martyrs denied Christ when forced under the punishment of death, the sin would not count since it was not freely chosen. Basically, they wouldn't commit a mortal sin since the mortal sin requires freedom of choice.

But some theologians disagree and supposedly they would still have to repent and confess their sin. What is the Catholic perspective on this?

If it's not a sin why were the martyrs willing to die if denying wouldn't be even considered rejection of their faith under this circumstance?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article on Donatism. That heresy was to refuse to forgive people who turned in their Scriptures to avoid persecution. The Catholic Church permitted penance and offered forgiveness to those who repented.

Comment: @https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20797/paul-chernoch forgiveness and reintegration decreases alienation - The Catholic approach avoided further isolating and marginalizing lapsed Christians, reducing divisiveness. The Donatist hardline exclusion of sinners likely increased alienation. Wise choice

Answer (score 2):

According to the Catholic Church, denying Christ under the threat of death is not a mortal sin because it is not freely chosen. Mortal sin requires complete consent, and fear does not take away involuntariness.

[List of Mortal Sins Every Catholic Should Know](https://stmaryofthesevendolors.com/prayers-2/list-of-mortal-sins-every-catholic-should-know/)

In terms of Bible verses, there is no specific verse that addresses this issue directly. However, there are verses that suggest that denying Christ is a serious offense. For example, in Matthew 10:33, Jesus says, "But whoever denies me before others, I will deny before my heavenly Father"

[According to the Catholic Church, if one, faced with the threat of being burned alive, denied Christ, would his sin be mortal?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89818/according-to-the-catholic-church-if-one-faced-with-the-threat-of-being-burned)

This verse suggests that denying Christ is a serious offense that has consequences. On the other hand, there are also verses that suggest that God is merciful and forgiving. For example, in 1 John 1:9, it says, "If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just and will forgive us our sins and purify us from all unrighteousness".

Comment: My question seems to be a duplicate of https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89818/according-to-the-catholic-church-if-one-faced-with-the-threat-of-being-burned